# Was this a valid draw?

Tags: rules, claim-draw

I was playing this game in-person with someone and I was white. My opponent had a pawn on a7 and kept moving his king back and forth  between c6 and d6 at least 3-4 times while I maneuvered my bishop around the board to capture his pawn on a7 to make room for my past pawn. After I captured his pawn on a7 he moved his king back to d6 and claimed it was a draw because at that time he had moved his king back and forth on the same 2 squares 6 times. I understand the 3 fold repetition but his king had other squares to move and wasn't in a perpetual check. Was this a valid draw?[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it was not a draw. For a draw by three-fold repetition, the exact position, and all of the possible moves (castling and en passant, which since en passant can only happen on the move, in essence, it requires a fourth repetition of the position), have to be repeated three times.

It was clearly a case of your opponent not really knowing the rules.

It seems like he was somewhat confusing, and mixing, three-fold repetition with the 50-move rule, which requires 50 moves of just moving around without a pawn move or capture with repeating the position three times.

P.S. The repetitions do not need to be consecutive.

Comment: Many players especially newer ones and those who do not play in tournaments do not know all the rules.  I played someone at the club we had at the uni who did not know en passant.

Comment: Thanks Phish, I thought it was odd and I've never heard of a 6-move draw like that before. I don't play too often so I'm not too familiar with ruling like that. I just agreed for the game's sake but I know I was in a winning position to promote the pawn and pick off the rest.

Comment: Primarily YOUR figures didn't take part in the repetition - as your bishop moved with a clear goal and clearly changed and did not repeat its move

Comment: "P.S. The repetitions do not need to be consecutive." They don't? Must be hard to keep track then.

Comment: No, they do not. Considering the rule is really borne of tournaments, you keep score there, so there is proof. That said, it might be hard for a weaker player to realize they have had a three-fold repetition, but most experienced players have an idea they have repeated three times, and then they can just glance at their scoresheet to confirm. It might need to be a bit more obvious if you are playing blitz, and thus, in a row is easier to prove.

Comment: @Mast Yes. If someone claims a draw and the opponent doesn't agree that it's a draw, then in a tournament the arbiter needs to look at the scoresheets and replay the game to determine whether it actually is a draw. This can take a while.

Comment: @JiK I think that this was much more informal (on off-hand game) than that, and hopefully, presented with the evidence that it is not a draw, he would just agree, and acquiesce.